# Image doesn't load on production when i fetch path from Database(firebase) REACT

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i've been trying to show image on my website that i deploy with firebase hosting.

it kept being not found 'https:somewebsite/img/bonk.jpeg'

i tried to change the path many times on firestore.
i had to put my img in the public folder in order for them to be build.
Can someone tell me what is the default path to display img or if i did it wrong ?

I tried to change the path in the DB.
I also tried to change my image in different folder before the 'npm run build'.

Comment: I also tried to add "homepage" ="/"; on my package.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.